# Rails not recognizing changes to mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I have a rails app that uses mysql as the database.  I've done an sqldump, created a database (called local_prod), and imported the dump into the database.  When I try to access the database information with my rails app, it doesn't see any of the data that is in the database.  Any idea why this is happening?

When I call for the object I'm looking for through the web app, it returns nil.  Here is the sql select statement that is run:

```
Bound Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `bounds`.* FROM `bounds` WHERE `bounds`.`city` = 'boston' AND `bounds`.`state` = 'ma' ORDER BY `bounds`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

When I copy and paste that same statement into the mysql console in my terminal, it returns all the data I am looking for.

Here is my database.yml file as well:

```
development:
 adapter: mysql2
 database: local_prod 
 host: localhost
 username: root
 password:
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: can you access the data by rails console?

Comment: The rails console returns nil as well @KcUS_unico

Answer (score 0):

You sure your sql db doesn't have a root password?

Comment: I'm pretty sure.  I'm able to log use mysql in the terminal under root without a password and when I am attempting to access the desired data from the rails app it is returning nil and not undefined which I would think would be the case if I didn't have access to the db at all.